# Seeking a Classical quote for an epigraph

Tags: passage-request

I'm editing a short piece of writing set in early Imperial Rome, and seeking a Classical quotation to use as an epigraph.

The piece involves a woman whose arms and legs are twisted from birth, causing her to walk with a limp. She's rumored to have made a bargain with a dark entity, giving her evil magicks in exchange for some great price. (Rather stereotypical, but that's not out of the ordinary for Roman times.)

Does anyone know of a Classical quotation pertaining to any of these aspects: an injured leg due to a birth defect, making a deal with some unwholesome entity for power, or preferably both together?